# datatables can't get right Json

Tags: jquery, html, json, datatables

I have a problem with datatables and Json data.
Json seems ok , is validated but cant get datatables to work with. Get no errors, nada...
[image]

```
<table id="dtable3">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Listing Id</th>
    <th>Listing title</th>
    <th>Calendar Id</th>
    <th>Calendar Title</th>

</tr>
</thead>

<tfoot>
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Listing Id</th>
    <th>Listing title</th>
    <th>Calendar Id</th>
    <th>Calendar Title</th>

</tr>
</tfoot>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var dt=<?php echo $jsonList?>;

     $('#dtable3').DataTable({

        "pageLength": 10,
        data: dt,
        // data:dat,
        columns: [
            {
                "className": 'details-control',
                "orderable": false,
                data: null,
                "defaultContent": "<span class='showBookings glyphicon glyphicon-list'></span><span class='editCal glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span>"
            },
            {data: 'listing_id'},
            {data: 'title_1'},
            {data: 'calendar_id'},
            {data: 'calendar_title'},
        ],
    });
```

Cant figure whats wrong with this json or code cause i dont get errors or anything else...
Thanks for your time , apreciate very much your help.

Comment: Your code works fine, see https://jsfiddle.net/qhyj1288/1/. Most likely the problem is  in this line `var dt=<?php echo $jsonList?>;`. Can you view the source of the page and post what is actually shown in this line after interpreted by PHP?

Comment: @Gyrocode.com, see my now updated answer - he needs of course to JSON.parse() it - stupid me :(

Answer (score 1):

Since the code is working OK - **http://jsfiddle.net/Lz6u5t1s/1/** - the reason is that you need to parse the string that is echoed out via PHP :

```
var dt = JSON.parse(<?php echo $jsonList ?>);
```

Comment: @Gyrocode.com - the 2th link is an array datatype, OP is using JSON.  And you are referring to the wrong dataSrc - as I have mentioned in the answer -> https://www.datatables.net/examples/ajax/custom_data_property.html "_As an empty string (e.g. dataSrc: '') - the data source is not an object but an array_", OP can now insert and array of literals.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com, it appears you are right, the code actually works right away - dataSrc does not need to be resetted.  "Funny", I have always done that, perhaps we did that in 1.9.x? Somehow an example of cargo programming :(

Comment: If `$jsonList` is a result of `json_encode()` PHP function, it doesn't need to be parsed with `JSON.parse()` either, the problem must be elsewhere.